# Automatically build Sphinx documentation when a source file changes

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm using [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) to document one of my projects, and I like to preview my changes in my browser. I want to be able to save some changes to an `.rst` file, and be able to immediately refresh my browser and see the changes.

Essentially I want to automatically execute a `make html` whenever one of the `.rst` files is changed.

Answer (score 38):

You can use [sphinx-autobuild](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinx-autobuild). It will also automatically initiate a page refresh in the browser.

It is easy to use, for example:

```
sphinx-autobuild docs docs/_build/html
```

or, if you have a separate build dir,

```
sphinx-autobuild <doc-source-dir> <doc-build-dir>
```

where `<doc-source-dir>` is the source directory of your documentation and `<doc-build-dir>` is the directory where you want the built html files.

Answer (score 17):

Jacob Kaplan-Moss [has a good solution](http://jacobian.org/writing/auto-building-sphinx/):

```
pip install watchdog
watchmedo shell-command \
          --patterns="*.rst" \
          --ignore-pattern='_build/*' \
          --recursive \
          --command='make html'
```

Note, change the pattern to match your suffix. Jacob uses *.txt, but I needed to change it to *.rst.

Comment: If you using Firefox you could install Auto Reload add-on.

Comment: This worked for me.  I altered the command 'make html' to 'make html && xvkbd -window Firefox -text "\Cr"' to get automatic reloading.

Answer (score 4):

If you're on a *nix system, you can use inotify to monitor filesystem events and trigger actions.

For example, on ubuntu,

```
apt-get install inotify-tools
```

Then run a script like this to listen for events in a given dir

```
while true
  do
    inotifywait -r -e modify -e move -e create -e delete /tmp/docs | while read line
      do
        echo "file changed; time to run make html"
      done
  done
```

Comment: Instead of using 2 while loops you can also remove the outer loop by adding the `--monitor` (`-m`) switch to `inotifywait`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a macro in you favorite editor that saves the file and opens it in your browser, any text editor can do (geany, gedit, emacs, vi, notepad++...)

Comment: Not a bad idea... however I'd prefer something more portable. I really want to be able to just run `make html --auto-rebuild`

Comment: well you can always write a script that does that

Answer (score 0):

### Rebuild a page and refresh a preview in VSCode

If using [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/), install [Live Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.live-server), with [sphinx-build](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html) and [restructuredText](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/index.html) then, in a `zsh` terminal, from your doc root dir, in a single command you can:

- rebuild (`make html`),
- open a preview `build/html/doc.html`
- re-open the document you were editing `code -r source/doc.rst`

```
make html && code -r build/html/doc.html && code -r source/doc.rst
```

- `make html` will build the doc tree
- `code -r` will reuse the current window in both cases

If each of `doc.html`, the *live preview* of `doc.html`, and `doc.rst` are all open already, sphinx will rebuild the tree and vscode will open the refreshed preview, and return you to editing `doc.rst`.

### Take it one step further

and create a dynamic keybinding, which will do all of the above with a keyboard shortcut for any open `.rst` file.  Add this to your `keybindings.json`:

```json
   {
      "key": "cmd+shift+R",
      "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
      "args": {
        "text": "VSCODEOPENFILE=${file} && sphinx-build -M html ${VSCODEOPENFILE:h} ${${VSCODEOPENFILE:h}/source/build/} ${VSCODEOPENFILE} && code -r ${${VSCODEOPENFILE:h}/source/build/}${${VSCODEOPENFILE:t}/rst/html} && code -r ${VSCODEOPENFILE}\u000D"
      },
      "when": "textInputFocus && !editorReadonly"
    }
```

- `"key": "cmd+shift+R"` is the keyboard shortcut.  Run this when your `rst` file is in the active editor
- `"command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence"` tells vscode what to do (run the args as a command in the terminal)
- the command in `"args": { "text" :`

  - `VSCODEOPENFILE=${file}` will set the env var the currently open file path
  - `sphinx-build -M html ${VSCODEOPENFILE:h} ${${VSCODEOPENFILE:h}/source/build/} ${VSCODEOPENFILE} && code -r ${${VSCODEOPENFILE:h}/source/build/}${${VSCODEOPENFILE:t}/rst/html}` will run sphinx rebuild on just the current file

    - `-M html` use the html builder
    - `${VSCODEOPENFILE:h}` is the path to the `source` dir, e.g., `workspace/docs/source`
    - `${${VSCODEOPENFILE:h}/source/build/}` substitutes `build` for `source` to get the path to the build dir, e.g., `workspace/docs/build`
    - `code -r ${${VSCODEOPENFILE:h}/source/build/}${${VSCODEOPENFILE:t}/rst/html}` will substitute both `build` for `source` and `html` for `rst` in the argument (i.e., `source/doc.rst` will become `build/doc.html`,) and reopen it in the existing window, forcing the live preview to refresh
    - `code -r ${VSCODEOPENFILE}` will return you to the original window (e.g., `doc.rst`,) for editing.
- `when` setting will restrict the `Command-Shift-R` command to work when only when the editor is focused and not read-only.

**NOTE** this code is for mac os x and `zsh`, but will likely work elsewhere with a little tweaking

This resolved an issue for me with continuous autorebuilding by `sphinx-autobuild` due, I assume, to an `shutil.copyfile` in `conf.py`.  Also I tried a few vscode sphinx and rst-preview extensions, and none of them worked, either.